# SharePoint 2010 and browser support

Tags: browser-compatibility

Is there an out-of-the-box way of restricting browsers and versions from within SharePoint 2010? We have found that the user has the best experience on IE7+ for our intranet so we'd like to redirect the user to a friendly page on all other browsers. Can this be done easily or will we have to write custom code?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include some browser sniffing code in your masterpage.  This would require some custom code (either client javascript or server code).

With that said, the there is much better support in 2010 versus 2007 for Chrome, FireFox, and Safari.  Here is a full rundown on browser compatibility for SharePoint 2010.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Mike. So there's no simple configuration we can toggle to select IE7 and up?

Comment: No, it has to be included either client side or server side.  Using it in the master page would be the best approach to ensure each page is checked when rendered.  I had a link to a javascript library that could be used, but I can 't find it offhand.

Comment: There is nothing that allows you to only support specified browsers, that would have to be added in custom code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For those interested, this page talks about using client- and server-side code to detect browser and version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx#UsingHBC

Comment: As Mike said, there is support for IE, Firefox, and Safari (and with SP1, official support for Chrome). The only items that are IE specific are the few straggling ActiveX controls, or say the Silverlight controls on an iPad. If you've pushed customizations (ie: branding) that are not cross-browser compatible then you've undone some of the hard work Microsoft did to make it cross browser compatible in the first place.